# Remove gluon-mobile dialog at startup

Tags: java, android, javafx, javafxports, gluon-mobile

Am new to Android App Development using javafx (using javafxports & gluon-mobile) . 
Am I using gluon-Api to build my project by extending [**MobileApplication**](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.3.2/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/application/MobileApplication.html#MobileApplication--) class .
Using the [sample programs](http://gluonhq.com/support/samples/).Am trying to make my own version.
But,at the starting of the starting of the App Am getting this unwanted dialog.
         
Am talking about this dialog that keeps ***appearing at the Startup of the App.***

[image: Am talking about the dialog]

**Here's my Code**. I have extended the [**MobileApplication**](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.3.2/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/application/MobileApplication.html#MobileApplication--) class to create my own version of App based on the [samples](http://gluonhq.com/support/samples/).

```
    package com.gluonapplication;

    import com.gluonapplication.views.Home;
    import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication;
    import static com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.HOME_VIEW;

    /**
     *
     * @author Guru
     */
     public class MainApplication extends MobileApplication {

     public void init()
     {
      addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW,() -> new Home(HOME_VIEW).getView());


     }

     public void postinit()
     {

     }

     public void start()
     {

     }
     }
```

And here's the Home class that returns the home view for the App.

package com.gluonapplication.views;

```
    import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

    /**
     *
     * @author Guru
     */
    public class Home {
    View view; 
    String name;
    public Home(String name)
    {
    this.name=name;
    }


    public  View  getView()
    {
    try 
    {
        view=FXMLLoader.load(Home.class.getResource("HomeView.fxml"));

       view.setName(name);
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
     {
       Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return new View(name);
      }
      return view;
      }
      }
```

Here's *HomeView.fxml* file whose Root is View .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View?>
    <?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
    <?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?> 
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
    <View prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="350.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <center>
    < VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="15" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <children>
        <Label text="Welcome Back!" />
        <AnchorPane prefHeight="254.0" prefWidth="253.0">
           <children>
              <ImageView fitHeight="254.0" fitWidth="234.0" layoutX="56.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">

          </ImageView>
           </children>
        </AnchorPane>
        <JFXButton text="Continue" />
     </children>
  </VBox>
```

Thanks in Advance,Please help me stop this Dialog from Appearing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Gluon Mobile library that you are using in your project is not an open source library.

You can find all the info about it [here](http://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/buy/).

While you can fully try the library (100% functionality) for free, you will have this nag window showing up at startup time.

You can get rid of it by purchasing a license, or if it is an open source [project](http://gluonhq.com/programs/free-gluon-licenses/open-source-license-request/) or you are a [student](http://gluonhq.com/programs/free-gluon-licenses/student-license-request/).

Comment: So it seems , I'll have to apply the licence First and include it in my project at starting !